Daikin Mini Split Runs Constantly V2
While googling my issue I came across the following post which describes the exact behavior I am observing as well.
Daikin Mini Split Runs Constantly
I have three indoor units.
Two of them are Ftxm20m2v1b and the other one is Ftxm35m2v1b
The two Ftxm20m2v1b cycle off completely once reaching temp.
The one Ftxm35m2v1b reaches temp and holds there, but never cycles off (the outdoor unit is always running as well). On rare occasions I have observed the Ftxm35m2v1b cycling off, but this is not the norm and I am not sure under what circumstances this happens / how to trigger this "correct" behavior.
If I set the Ftxm35m2v1b temperature to a degree or two higher than the current room temp (measured with an external thermometer) the unit will continue to put out cold air but will allow the temperature to rise to the newly set temperature, and then continue to run while holding the set temperature.
If I set the Ftxm35m2v1b temperature three degrees or so (not an exact science) higher than the current room temperature, the unit will cycle off completely.
There was no solution/answer in the linked post. Does anyone else have an idea about what is going on here?

Have you contacted Daikin about the issue?   I have another brand units and the tech support was very helpful .  Hopefully Diken is the same.

No. Just been endlessly trying to figure out the situation myself but I will give that a try. Thanks for your reply
